# Is there any function to be called when user selects the option from Dropdown in @fluentui/react-northstar

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I want a function to be called when the user selects an option from the Dropdown Search Selection used by @fluentui/react-northstar.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from '@fluentui/react-northstar';

class someComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        inputItems: [
            'Robert Tolbert',
            'Wanda Howard',
            'Tim Deboer',
            'Amanda Brady',
            'Ashley McCarthy',
            'Cameron Evans',
            'Carlos Slattery',
            'Carole Poland',
            'Robin Counts',
          ]
    }
  }

  onBlurHandler(){
    //Handles onBlur of Dropdown
  }

  **FUNCTION TO BE CALLED WHEN USER SELECTS THE OPTIONS FROM INPUTITEMS**
  optionSelectedHandler() {
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
            search
            items={this.state.inputItems}
            onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
            placeholder="Start Typing"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default someComponent;
```

Can anyone provide the attribute which is to be used for handling the `optionSelectedHandler` function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to a Controlled Component.

First, you need to create a new attribute in the state to handle the `selectedOption`.

Then, you need to add it a `value` prop, and then add a `onChange` prop, this one should be you `optionSelectedHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

As was answered by @maxpsz, you should pass your function to the `onChange` prop. Unfortunately this is poorly documented, but a little experiment shows that this function receives this object:

```
{
 items: Array(9)
 placeholder: "Select your hero"
 onChange: ƒ optionSelectedHandler() {}
 align: "start"
 clearIndicator: Object
 itemToString: ƒ itemToString() {}
 itemToValue: ƒ itemToValue() {}
 list: Object
 position: "below"
 toggleIndicator: Object
 triggerButton: Object
 searchQuery: "Tim Deboer"
 open: false
 highlightedIndex: 2
 value: "Tim Deboer"
}
```

in its *second* argument.

So you can write your component with the selection handler like this:

```
const DropdownExample = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

  function optionSelectedHandler(alwaysNull, data) {
    setSelectedItem(data.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown
        items={inputItems}
        placeholder="Select your hero"
        onChange={optionSelectedHandler}
      />
      <p>You selected: {selectedItem}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

You can see a working example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-17hf6?file=/example.js).

Having said all that, I think there are much better React component libraries out there. This one has the API that is awkward, ugly, and poorly documented.